# Blender 2.8 no background image in wireframe mode

Tags: camera, image

I am modelling a scene from a photo. As I am doing so, I need the wireframe mode to show the background image as well to see where I should position objects. However, the background image only appears in solid mode, not wireframe. I am using an fSpy file as the camera calibration. Initially, the wireframe mode had the background image, but now it doesn't show anything.[image]
The wireframe mode doesn't have the background image.
[image]

Comment: If you use import image as plane it will not display in wireframe. If you add an image->Background, it will stay visible in wireframe.

Comment: It's just bring an image to front hiding a geo. P.S. For the nightly build(2.80.74) by 07/05/2019 the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the camera selected, in the "add image / depth back / front" menu select front